# Best Way to View my TukeyHSD Output in R

Tags: r

So i am running an ANOVA on blood pressure data with 3 factors: Group (Normal and Concussed), Age (6-24), and Pain Score (0-10).

```
SBP.aov <- aov(SBP~Group*AgeW*PainScore, data=df)
tuk.SBP <- TukeyHSD(SBP.aov,'Group:AgeW:PainScore')
tuk.SBP
```

When i print it, i get the error  `[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 75710 rows ]` I know about using `options(max.print=10000000)` and that works around it, but i still cannot see all the comparisons in the console output. I know a lot of them are going to be meaningless to look at, but it is a lot of factors look at and i was wondering if there was a better way to go about this as i cannot see it all in the R Console output. Anyone have any way of going about this to get the meaningful comparisons or an easier way of looking at the data?

I am using Windows 7 64-Bit Enterprise with the RGui (64-Bit) - R Console program, version 3.2.2.

Comment: There is a plot method for `TukeyHSD`, so `plot(tuk.SBP)`. If it's still too much, try filtering out certain ranges. See the example in `?TukeyHSD`, but basically it's `x$tension` if you are modeling a variable `tension`, for example.

Comment: The most important of this would be Pain Score and Group. Separating it out, would you suggest just doing it for each age? Wouldn't that mean i have to do an Anova for each age, but would be less powerful because many comparisons would be missing?

Comment: I was suggesting to save the result of `TukeyHSD` and filter that.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to R and therefore cannot provide much guidance in terms of a work-around for your issue, but in my own work with Tukey's HSD I've used the package 'agricolae" with some success, so if you are just looking for a nice way to visualize your data, you could try that... I don't know how well it handles huge datasets, but you could give it a try.